# Why can't I connect to my server in some instances?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, port-forwarding, ipv6

I have created a server that is connected my home network. Although this should not be relevant to the question, it is running Ubuntu 22.04, and right now I am running (and trying to connect to) the Apache default web page in HTTPS mode on a high-end port.
I am attempting to configure my router so that this server will become exposed to the general internet. My ISP is Verizon, my IPv4 is supposedly not in CGNAT range, I have set my IPv6 address to static, and my router has several methods to apparently accomplish this. According to my understanding:

1. There is DMZ hosting, which apparently allows my server to be entirely exposed to the internet. This has IPv4 and IPv6 modes.
2. There is IPv6 pinholes, which should allow traffic to flow in and out of a single port at my IPv6 host.
3. There is IPv4 port forwarding, which should allow traffic going to my router IPv4 at a particular port to get to my server at a particular port.

I have several test cases to check if my sever is being connected to properly:

1. Can I connect to the server from within my local WiFi network?
2. Can I connect to the server from my phone when I am using data (the WiFi is disconnected, but my provider is also Verizon)?
3. Can I connect to the server from a nearby café?
4. Can I connect (using cURL) to the server from various AWS EC2 instances?

Many of these cases seemingly do not work. I can always access the server in test case 1, using IPv4 or IPv6. Using a combination of IPv6 port forwarding and IPv6 DMZ, I can access my server in test case 2 and 4 (but only one AWS instance). In case 3 or using other AWS instances than the one that I originally tried, which continues to work, it returns a Network is unreachable error. I am using the local IPv6 address that my server says that it has, but I believe that this is under my router's address and should be able to be routed to even from outside(?). IPv4 port forwarding and DMZ, so far, appears to work correctly, though I haven't tested case 3 yet, but why would IPv6 work in some cases but not others? Am I attempting to connect to it incorrectly? Also, is my understanding of my router's settings correct?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you connect _out_ from the network using IPv6?

Comment: Your understanding of port forwarding is correct.     You may have a crappy router that is broken and does not let you do stuff on port 80 (and/or 443) because it has a local server and its badly coded.  You should mention the model of your router.